# How to make an excel file uneditable?

Tags: asp.net, import

There is an Excel file which I import from a specific network path or local path, and that Excel file is exported from another vendor aplication. The problem is that the Excel file is editable.

Is there any way I can lock the Excel file or make it un-editable? It would be acceptable to apply this lock and/or remove the editability from the containing folder as well.

Comment: Have you changed the permissions to the file on the machine where it is located? i.e. File properties - check 'Read only'?

Comment: ya that is not the solution because any user can change the property setting. i want some thing i can do it by code. or to lock the File.

Comment: How is the file being exported? User initiated from vendor application?

Comment: its been exported to a specfic shared folder from vendor apllication.

Answer (score 2):

An Excel spreadsheet can have a password to modify.  Under Save, click on the Tools dropdown and then General Options.  If you implement this, the spreadsheet can not be modified unless you know the password.

[image: modify password]

Answer (score 1):

You can make cells uneditable in excel, by using the "protect" option.

Could any of the following links help you?

[Link 1 Locking cells](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=83241)

[Link 2 generated by asp.net](http://www.technade.com/2008/11/how-to-lock-excel-sheet-generated-by.html)